# Magento 2 move reviews form inside list.phtml file

Tags: magento2, php, layout, xml

By default magento 2 review structure is like this -

`/templates/review.phtml` and inside it you have -
`/product/view/list.phtml` and `Magento_Review/templates/form.phtml` files.

`form.phtml` file is called using `<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>` in `review.phtml` file

What I want to do - 
remove that getChildHtml part from review.phtml file to make form disappear. So far I get it to work. I have successfully removed my review form. Now I want to add my form back but inside `list.phtml` file and call it using getChildHtml. How can I do this? So far what I have tried ended with no luck.

Final result should be that in `list.phtml` file I call my form like this - `<?= $block->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>` and it should appear in place I put him

Thank you for any advice! :)

Comment: Can you add the full path of file where you want to add the review form?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Inside - /module-review/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml

Comment: And where are you calling the list.phtml?

Comment: @SukumarGorai In its default place - inside review.phtml file. Basically what I want to do - remove form from review.phtml file and call it inside list.phtml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by following steps:

**Step 1(Adding form in review list.phtml):**

Create **review_product_listajax.xml** under below location:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Review/layout/review_product_listajax.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data">
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey"/>
            <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

**Step 2:**

Copy the below file:

> vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml

to your theme:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Review/templates/product/view/list.phtml

and add the `<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>` code block to desired location of that file.

**Step 3(remove form from default location):**

Create **catalog_product_view.xml** to below location:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Review/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and add the below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
            <referenceBlock name="product.review.form" remove="true"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Above code will remove the default form place and add ti list block. Flush the cache and test.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding! You can also upvote the answer.

Comment: Hey, just noticed that my reviews arent saved anymore. Submitted review but didnt appear in reviews (also no message was shown that review successfully saved). And I also noticed that in console there is error - "magento 2 syntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" Can you help please?

Comment: You need to check the submit url of your form if its not showing correctly then you need to add the url correctly .

Comment: url seems to be correct. Noticed if I delete "review_product_listajax.xml" then no error is thrown, so some part is missing in that file probably

Comment: I need to check it then.

Comment: hey, any luck? I still havent managed to fix this, dont know what I am missing...

Comment: Issue was with formkey. I have updated my answer please check, its working perfectly. Only need to update review_product_listajax.xml